# Android: java equivalent of android:button Attribute?

Tags: java, android, xml, image, resources

Is there a pure-java way of setting the android:button attribute? My use case is I have some radio buttons with custom on/off images. They are currently in xml, but for several reasons I want their creation to be done in pure java. Currently the `android:button` references a `<selector>` xml file:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/red_down_full" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_down" /> 
</selector>
```

Is there any way to either

- reference the `<selector>` xml file in java
- skip the `<selector>` entirely and just set the `state_checked` image in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can set the xml image selector via code. If you want to set the selector on your `RadioButton` you have to call its `setButtonDrawable(idOfYourSelector)`.

The code will be like this:

```
((RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.yourRadioButton)).setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.yourSelector);
```

If you want to set only the image you used for `state_checked`, then you need to supply the id of your `state_checked` image on `setButtonDrawable(idOfYourImage)` instead the id of your selector. In your case it will be:

```
((RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.yourRadioButton)).setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.red_down_full);
```

To ensure that it will not overlap the label of your `RadioButton`, you have to know the width of your `drawable`. Then set the left padding of your `RadioButton` depending on the width of your `drawable`. This will ensure the image for your `RadioButton` will not overlap its label.

Comment: That still leaves the original radio button image overlaid on top of the background though; and `setButtonDrawable` leaves the image (which is somewhat large) clipped off to the bounding-box of the original radio button; neither seems to do what `android:button="..."` does

Comment: @LiHaoyi: Sorry for that. I thought you were asking about Button, not RadioButton. I already updated my answer.

Comment: @LiHaoyi: The solution is to set the left padding of your RadioButton accordingly. :)

Comment: Got it working. I realize I didn't specify whether it was radiobutton or button, because I didn't think it would make a difference. Thanks =)